# Is the family of probabilities generated by a random walk on a finitely generated amenable group asymptotically invariant?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, random-walks

Is the family of probabilities $\mu^n$ (convolution) generated by a random walk $\mu$ on a finitely generated amenable group $G$ asymptotically invariant ($\|g\mu^n-\mu\|_{L^1}\to 0$ for any $g\in G$)?

I am not familiar with random walks on amenable groups. Please indicate reference on the subject.

Comment: typo: the last $\mu$ should be $\mu^n$

Comment: Can you edit the post?  The button "edit" should be visible just below the tags.

Comment: A trivial (and possibly degenerate) counterexample is, for instance, when $G$ is infinite cyclic (or cyclic of even order) and $\mu$ is supported by odd numbers: then $\|g\mu^n-\mu^n\|=1$ for every odd $g$. We can avoid this, for instance assuming that $\mu(\{1\})\neq 0$.